# Android fileNotFoundException while creating a file

Tags: android, filenotfoundexception

For some reason Android puts a "/" in front of the file name, which is a problem because then, I cant access the file because of the following error:

The file is located at /data/data/tk.yteditors.london2013/files/

How do I resolve this and prevent the File class from adding a "/" in front of my file?

If you need more details, just ask.

```
01-23 16:59:15.174: W/System.err(26732): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /1043005842.html: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
01-23 16:59:15.204: W/System.err(26732):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:416)
01-23 16:59:15.204: W/System.err(26732):    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:78)
01-23 16:59:15.214: W/System.err(26732):    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:105)
01-23 16:59:15.214: W/System.err(26732):    at tk.yteditors.london2013.lib.ftp.SimpleFTP.stor(SimpleFTP.java:151)
01-23 16:59:15.214: W/System.err(26732):    at tk.yteditors.london2013.ConfirmActivity.sendFtp(ConfirmActivity.java:109)
01-23 16:59:15.214: W/System.err(26732):    at tk.yteditors.london2013.ConfirmActivity$1.run(ConfirmActivity.java:92)
01-23 16:59:15.214: W/System.err(26732):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
01-23 16:59:15.224: W/System.err(26732): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
01-23 16:59:15.224: W/System.err(26732):    at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
01-23 16:59:15.224: W/System.err(26732):    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
01-23 16:59:15.224: W/System.err(26732):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:400)
01-23 16:59:15.224: W/System.err(26732):    ... 6 more
```

Activator Code:

```
public void sendFtp() throws Exception{
    SimpleFTP ftp = new SimpleFTP();
    ftp.connect("<SECRET_IP>", 21, "<SECRET_UN>", "<SECRET_PASS>");
    ftp.bin();
    ftp.stor(new File(getIntent().getExtras().getString("fileName")));
    ftp.disconnect();
}
```

Other code:

```
package tk.yteditors.london2013.lib.ftp;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;


/**
 * SimpleFTP is a simple package that implements a Java FTP client.
 * With SimpleFTP, you can connect to an FTP server and upload multiple files.
 *  <p>
 * Copyright Paul Mutton,
 *           <a href="http://www.jibble.org/">http://www.jibble.org/</a>
 * 
 */
public class SimpleFTP {


/**
 * Create an instance of SimpleFTP.
 */
public SimpleFTP() {

}


/**
 * Connects to the default port of an FTP server and logs in as
 * anonymous/anonymous.
 */
public synchronized void connect(String host) throws IOException {
    connect(host, 21);
}


/**
 * Connects to an FTP server and logs in as anonymous/anonymous.
 */
public synchronized void connect(String host, int port) throws IOException {
    connect(host, port, "anonymous", "anonymous");
}


/**
 * Connects to an FTP server and logs in with the supplied username
 * and password.
 */
public synchronized void connect(String host, int port, String user, String pass) throws IOException {
    if (socket != null) {
        throw new IOException("SimpleFTP is already connected. Disconnect first.");
    }
    socket = new Socket(host, port);
    reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
    writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));

    String response = readLine();
    if (response.startsWith("220")) {

    } else{
        throw new IOException("SimpleFTP received an unknown response when connecting to the FTP server: " + response);
    }

    sendLine("USER " + user);

    response = readLine();
    if (!response.startsWith("331") && !response.startsWith("220")) {
        throw new IOException("SimpleFTP received an unknown response after sending the user: " + response);
    }

    sendLine("PASS " + pass);

    response = readLine();
    if (!response.startsWith("230") && !response.startsWith("220")) {
        throw new IOException("SimpleFTP was unable to log in with the supplied password: " + response);
    }

    // Now logged in.
}


/**
 * Disconnects from the FTP server.
 */
public synchronized void disconnect() throws IOException {
    try {
        sendLine("QUIT");
    }
    finally {
        socket = null;
    }
}


/**
 * Returns the working directory of the FTP server it is connected to.
 */
public synchronized String pwd() throws IOException {
    sendLine("PWD");
    String dir = null;
    String response = readLine();
    if (response.startsWith("257")) {
        int firstQuote = response.indexOf('\"');
        int secondQuote = response.indexOf('\"', firstQuote + 1);
        if (secondQuote > 0) {
            dir = response.substring(firstQuote + 1, secondQuote);
        }
    }
    return dir;
}


/**
 * Changes the working directory (like cd). Returns true if successful.
 */   
public synchronized boolean cwd(String dir) throws IOException {
    sendLine("CWD " + dir);
    String response = readLine();
    return (response.startsWith("250"));
}


/**
 * Sends a file to be stored on the FTP server.
 * Returns true if the file transfer was successful.
 * The file is sent in passive mode to avoid NAT or firewall problems
 * at the client end.
 */
public synchronized boolean stor(File file) throws IOException {
    if (file.isDirectory()) {
        throw new IOException("SimpleFTP cannot upload a directory.");
    }

    String filename = file.getName();

    return stor(new FileInputStream(file.getName()), filename);
}

/**
 * Sends a file to be stored on the FTP server.
 * Returns true if the file transfer was successful.
 * The file is sent in passive mode to avoid NAT or firewall problems
 * at the client end.
 */
public synchronized boolean stor(InputStream inputStream, String filename) throws IOException {

    BufferedInputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(inputStream);

    sendLine("PASV");
    String response = readLine();
    if (!response.startsWith("227")) {
        throw new IOException("SimpleFTP could not request passive mode: " + response);
    }

    String ip = null;
    int port = -1;
    int opening = response.indexOf('(');
    int closing = response.indexOf(')', opening + 1);
    if (closing > 0) {
        String dataLink = response.substring(opening + 1, closing);
        StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(dataLink, ",");
        try {
            ip = tokenizer.nextToken() + "." + tokenizer.nextToken() + "." + tokenizer.nextToken() + "." + tokenizer.nextToken();
            port = Integer.parseInt(tokenizer.nextToken()) * 256 + Integer.parseInt(tokenizer.nextToken());
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            throw new IOException("SimpleFTP received bad data link information: " + response);
        }
    }

    sendLine("STOR " + filename);

    Socket dataSocket = new Socket(ip, port);

    response = readLine();
    if (!response.startsWith("150")) {
        throw new IOException("SimpleFTP was not allowed to send the file: " + response);
    }

    BufferedOutputStream output = new BufferedOutputStream(dataSocket.getOutputStream());
    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
    int bytesRead = 0;
    while ((bytesRead = input.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }
    output.flush();
    output.close();
    input.close();

    response = readLine();
    return response.startsWith("226");
}


/**
 * Enter binary mode for sending binary files.
 */
public synchronized boolean bin() throws IOException {
    sendLine("TYPE I");
    String response = readLine();
    return (response.startsWith("200"));
}


/**
 * Enter ASCII mode for sending text files. This is usually the default
 * mode. Make sure you use binary mode if you are sending images or
 * other binary data, as ASCII mode is likely to corrupt them.
 */
public synchronized boolean ascii() throws IOException {
    sendLine("TYPE A");
    String response = readLine();
    return (response.startsWith("200"));
}


/**
 * Sends a raw command to the FTP server.
 */
private void sendLine(String line) throws IOException {
    if (socket == null) {
        throw new IOException("SimpleFTP is not connected.");
    }
    try {
        writer.write(line + "\r\n");
        writer.flush();
        if (DEBUG) {
            System.out.println("> " + line);
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        socket = null;
        throw e;
    }
}

private String readLine() throws IOException {
    String line = reader.readLine();
    if (DEBUG) {
        System.out.println("< " + line);
    }
    return line;
}

private Socket socket = null;
private BufferedReader reader = null;
private BufferedWriter writer = null;

private static boolean DEBUG = false;


}
```

Whatever I do, if I give it the full path, it removes all path separators and only shows the last folder name, WITH A SLASH IN FRONT
and if i just give it the file, it PUTS A SLASH IN FRONT

PS. You can see i'm frustrated...

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to just edit the file location string to account for the added '/' (you might needed to use '../' too).

Please not that without seeing your code I can't confirm that this would work.

EDIT: Looking at your code, editing the variable filename, to delete the first '/' character should allow you to correct for the added '/'.